# Relation between tautological line bundle and blow up at the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, projective-varieties, line-bundles

We can define the projective $n$-space $\mathbb{P}^n$ as the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\}$ by the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ with all weights equal to $1$.

Moreover we can define the **tautological line bundle** of $\mathbb{P}^n$ as
$$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\mid v=tu \text{ for some $t\in\mathbb{C}$} \}.$$
But this definition is equal to the definition of the blow-up at the origin $0$ of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.
I'd like to understand how this definitions talk to each other: at the moment I've a naive idea of what a blow-up is and I've just started talking about line bundles, but I ddon't have a clear idea in mind of the connection between these two objects (and moreover if $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-a)
$ can still has a similar interpretation, or is it just a peculiar property of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)$).

I know this question may sound too vague, but I hope someone can give me some advice on how to see the tautological line bundle as a blow-up.

Comment: Dear @Aqua, I think I don't have enough background to understand your question: I'm pretty sure this is the definition of *tautological line bundle*, and since I'm a beginner in this area I've neverd heard of topological line bundles (but I'm sure what you're asking is legitimate). Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: @Aqua It is the tautological line bundle, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle).

Comment: See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336504).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way these definitions "talk to each other" has to do with the two projections onto the factors. If you map to $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, you get the blowup. If you map to $\mathbb P^n$, the same variety is realized as the tautological line bundle. The intuitive connection is that blowing up the origin of a vector space separates all of the one-dimensional linear subspaces so that they no longer intersect. These linear spaces correspond precisely to points of $\mathbb P^n$.

Another way to say the same thing is that the projection $\mathbb C^{n+1} \setminus 0 \to \mathbb P^n$ can be thought of as a rational map $\mathbb C^{n+1} \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^n$ with indeterminacy at the origin, so you have a copy of $\mathbb C^*$ as the fiber over each point of $\mathbb P^n$. Blowing up turns the origin (playing the role of vector space origin for all of these $\mathbb C^*$'s) into a copy of $\mathbb P^n$ (the zero section) that now has one point that *is* the origin of each fiber, so the fibers are now $\mathbb C$ and you can honestly call this thing a line bundle (instead of just a $\mathbb C^*$-bundle).

To see a similar interpretation of the other line bundles on projective space, I would take a look at Daniel Huybrechts' book *Complex Geometry*.

Comment: Your answer is brilliant! I'll definitely take a look at Huybrechts' book, thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the kind words! My favorite thing about Huybrecht's exposition is that (if you're working in complex algebraic geometry and willing to accept analytic arguments via GAGA) it instantly shows why all of the negative degree line bundles have no sections as a consequence of (basically) Liouville's theorem.